# Busca avançada PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela chamada **veiculo_cadastrado** com os seguintes campos:

`id_cadastro`, 
           `id_user`, 
           `status`, 
           `estado_veiculo`, 
           `tipo_cadastro`, 
           `fabricante_veiculo`, 
           `modelo_veiculo`, 
           `ano_fabricacao`, 
           `ano_modelo`, 
           `cor_veiculo`, 
           `combutivel_veiculo`, 
           `portas_veiculo`, 
           `cambio_veiculo`, 
           `kilometragem_veiculo`, 
           `dono_veiculo`, 
           `cidade_veiculo`, 
           `valor_veiculo`, 
           `descricao_veiculo`, 
           `placa_veiculo`, 
           `renavam_veiculo`, 
           `nome_documento`, 
           `alienado_veiculo`, 
           `certificado_veiculo`, 
           `garantia_veiculo`, 
           `ipva_veiculo`, 
           `licenciado_veiculo`, 
           `revisoes_veiculo`, 
           `revisoes_concessionaria`

Minha busca avançada vai gira em torno dos campos `fabricante_veiculo`, `modelo_veiculo`, `ano_fabricacao`, `ano_modelo`, `valor_veiculo`(valor mínimo e valor máximo) e teria um campo de texto livre para o usuário digitar uma busca. Eu não tenho ideia de como começa alguém tem algum exemplo?

Comment: Da uma pesquisada meu caro. Isso envolve WHERES,BETWEENS, LIKE e etc. Da uma pesquisa sobre isso

Comment: A minha maior dúvida é q como os campos n vão ser sempre preenchidos eu devo fazer um If de verificação pra cada input ou tem outro jeito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa criar o formulário de busca com os campos que citou, isso pode ser com tags  para alguns mas para o valor acho que vai precisar criar um "range", tipo valor entre X e Y.

Exemplo do form:

```
<form method="get" action="busca.php">

<label for="fabricante">Fabricante:</label>
<select name="fabricante" id="fabricante">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option value="11">Honda</option>
    <option value="22">Suzuki</option>
</select>

<label for="preco">Faixa de preços:</label>
<select name="preco" id="preco">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option value="0-10000">até R$ 10.000</option>
    <option value="10000-20000">Entre R$ 10.000 e R$ 20.000</option>
    <option value="20000-30000">Entre R$ 20.000 e R$ 30.000</option>
    <option value="30000-50000">Entre R$ 30.000 e R$ 50.000</option>
    <option value="50000-0">Acima de R$ 50.000</option>
</select>

<label for="busca">Termo:</label>
<input type="text" name="busca" id="busca" placeholder="Digite um termo para pesquisa">

<input type="submit" value="Buscar">
</form>
```

No PHP você precisa verificar quais campos o usuário definiu para montar a query.

Exemplo do PHP

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM veiculo_cadastrado WHERE (1=1)";


if ($_GET['fabricante'] != "") {
    $sql .= " AND fabricante_veiculo = '{$_GET['fabricante']}'";
}

if ($_GET['preco'] != "") {

    switch ($_GET['preco']) {
        case '0-10000':
            $sql .= " AND valor_veiculo < 10000";
            break;
        case '10000-20000':
            $sql .= " AND valor_veiculo BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000";
            break;
        case '20000-30000':
            $sql .= " AND valor_veiculo BETWEEN 20000 AND 30000";
            break;
        case '30000-50000':
            $sql .= " AND valor_veiculo BETWEEN 30000 AND 50000";
            break;
        case '50000-0':
            $sql .= " AND valor_veiculo >= 10000";
            break;
    }

    $sql .= " AND fabricante_veiculo = '{$_GET['fabricante']}'";
}

if ($_GET['busca'] != "") {
    $sql .= " AND modelo_veiculo LIKE '%{$_GET['busca']}%'";
}


//Executa a consulta com a query pronta
mysql_query($sql);
```

Você vai precisar adaptar o código para suas necessidades, mas acho que o básico para montar uma busca está aí.

Basicamente você define um WHERE (1=1) e depois vai concatenando o restante da string com os campos que o usuário definiu. Pode ser uma boa escolha usar uma função de filtro como mysql_escape_string() para os campos livres para preenchimento do usuário. Ou melhor ainda se você fizer as consultas usando PDO, mas isso já é outro assunto..